# Interseção entre tempo

Tags: java, data

Estou em duvida sobre o que utilizar na criação de um projeto de simulação de cinema. Até o momento tenho uma classe `Sessao`:

```
package entidades;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Sessao {
    private String nomeFilme;
    private LocalTime horarioDoFilme;
    private Duration duracaoDoFilme;

    public Sessao(String nome, LocalTime horario, Duration duracao) {
        this.nomeFilme = nome;
        this.horarioDoFilme = horario;
        this.duracaoDoFilme = duracao;
    }

    public Duration getDuracaoDoFilme() {

        return duracaoDoFilme;
    }

    public void setDuracaoDoFilme(Duration duracaoDoFilme) {

        this.duracaoDoFilme = duracaoDoFilme;
    }

    public String getNomeFilme() {

        return nomeFilme;
    }

    public void setNomeFilme(String nomeFilme) {

        this.nomeFilme = nomeFilme;
    }

    public LocalTime getHorarioDoFilme() {

        return horarioDoFilme;
    }

    public void setHorarioDoFilme(LocalTime tempoFilme) {

        this.horarioDoFilme = tempoFilme;
    }



    public String toString() {
        return "\nFilme: " + nomeFilme +
                "\nHorário: " + horarioDoFilme +
                "\nDuração: " + duracaoDoFilme;
    }
}
```

Em uma outra classe do projeto tenho o método `adicionarSessao()`. O mesmo recebe um id de uma sala e obviamente uma nova sessão. Porém, só posso adicionar uma sessão após testar se a duração de uma nova sessão não interfere na outra.

Gostaria de uma ajuda na hora de descobrir se há interseção, pois não estou conseguindo pensar em uma logica pra isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia básica é obter o horário que a sessão termina (somando a duração com o horário inicial), e verificar se o término é depois do início da outra sessão (se for, elas interferem uma na outra).

Então na classe `Sessao` você pode adicionar um método que faz essa verificação:

```
public class Sessao {
    public boolean interfere(Sessao outra) {
        Sessao antes, depois;
        if (this.horarioDoFilme.isBefore(outra.horarioDoFilme)) {
            antes = this;
            depois = outra;
        } else {
            antes = outra;
            depois = this;
        }

        return antes
            // calcula horário de término = horário de início + duração
            .horarioDoFilme.plus(antes.duracaoDoFilme)
            // verifica se o término é depois do início da sessão seguinte
            .isAfter(depois.horarioDoFilme);
    }
}
```

Primeiro eu vejo qual sessão começa antes, usando o [método `isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-).

Em seguida, eu calculo o horário de término da sessão que começa antes (usando o [método `plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#plus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) para somar a duração com o horário inicial) e verifico se esse término ocorre depois que a outra sessão já começou (com o [método `isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-)).

Caso a primeira sessão termine depois que a outra já começou, é porque elas interferem uma na outra (e nesse caso, o método `interfere` retorna `true`). Testando:

```
// filme com 2 horas de duração, começa as 14h
Sessao s1 = new Sessao("A", LocalTime.of(14, 0), Duration.ofHours(2));
// filme com 2 horas de duração, começa as 15h
Sessao s2 = new Sessao("B", LocalTime.of(15, 0), Duration.ofHours(2));
// filme com 2 horas de duração, começa as 17h
Sessao s3 = new Sessao("C", LocalTime.of(17, 0), Duration.ofHours(2));

System.out.println(s1.interfere(s2)); // true
System.out.println(s1.interfere(s3)); // false
System.out.println(s2.interfere(s3)); // false
```

Repare que `s2` termina às 17h, que é o mesmo horário que `s3` começa. O algoritmo acima considera que se termina exatamente no mesmo horário, então não há interferência.

Mas se quiser considerar que "exatamente o mesmo horário" também é interferência, basta mudar o retorno do método `interfere` para:

```
return ! antes
    // calcula horário de término = horário de início + duração
    .horarioDoFilme.plus(antes.duracaoDoFilme)
    // verifica se o término é depois do início da sessão seguinte
    .isBefore(depois.horarioDoFilme);
```

Agora eu uso `!` (que é o operador de negação) e troquei a chamada para [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-). Ou seja, agora a lógica é verificar se a primeira sessão **não** termina antes do início da outra (o que quer dizer que ou ela termina no mesmo horário, ou depois). Usando esta implementação, `s2.interfere(s3)` retorna `true`.

---

No caso, para adicionar uma nova sessão, você teria que verificar se ela não interfere em nenhuma outra (ou seja, teria que chamar o método `intefere` várias vezes, comparando a nova sessão com todas as outras já existentes).

Outro detalhe é que um [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) só possui informações sobre o horário, mas não sobre a data. Ou seja, se a sessão começar próxima da meia-noite, ela pode terminar na madrugada do dia seguinte, e as comparações acima falham. Ex: se começa 11 da noite e tem duração de 2 horas, o código acima falha, pois o horário de término é 1 da manhã, que um `LocalTime` considera que é antes de onze da noite, já que esta classe não leva em conta o dia.

Se quiser considerar também esses casos, eu sugiro mudar os horários da sessão para [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) (que possui data e hora, assim ao somar a duração, as datas são corretamente ajustadas para o dia seguinte, caso necessário), ou ainda [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), se quiser considerar também o fuso horário e casos mais complicados, como as mudanças de horário de verão. Ambos possuem os métodos `plus` para somar uma duração, e `isAfter` e `isBefore` para fazer comparações.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: O Java adotou alguma coisa da JodaTIme?

Comment: @Maniero Segundo o próprio Stephen Colebourne, algumas ideias e conceitos foram aproveitados, mas outras coisas que ele considerava "erradas" ou ruins, ele aproveitou para corrigir. Tem mais detalhes no blog dele, [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) e [aqui](http://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html). Ele mesmo diz que a API `java.time` seria mais "inspirada" no Joda-Time, do que uma simples cópia...