# Por que eu deveria ou não usar a Joda-Time?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

A pergunta vem principalmente baseada no [comentário de um dos nossos usuários mais ativos atualmente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413637/101) e que já demonstrou um conhecimento extraordinário em uso de tempo, principalmente em Java.

> a API java.time seria mais "inspirada" no Joda-Time, do que uma simples cópia
>
> algumas ideias e conceitos foram aproveitados, mas outras coisas que ele considerava "erradas" ou ruins, ele aproveitou para corrigir

Eu perguntava sobre se o Java, que eu sei que melhorou sua API, aproveitou algo da [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Então queria entender melhor o que ela tem de errado e se ainda tem algum motivo para usá-la se a API do Java aproveitou ideias dela.

Me interessa como curioso porque não uso Java, mas uso a NodaTime (inspirada na Joda-Time) que considero boa e já vi algumas coisas que ela é melhor que a Joda-Time, quem sabe eu poderia ter uma visão melhor da NodaTime entendendo mais sobre a Joda-Time. Seria um adendo interessante se for pertinente e tiver conhecimento.

Comment: @Manieiro, não sei responder sua pergunta, mas tem um post no EN que questiona os contras do joda, tendo em vista a dificuldade da pergunta, talvez ajude em algo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375544/are-there-any-cons-to-using-joda-time, fiquei curioso com a sua pergunta e estou pesquisando também.

Comment: @Scarabelo já ajudou. Eu imagino que o hkotsubo vai responder nos próximos dias :) MEu objetivo é realmente provocar uma retrospectiva sobre como essa lib é, o que ela tem de problema e como o Java melhorou quando se inspirou nela. Admito que minha maior curiosidade tem a ver com a NodaTime que também se inspirou e não sei se ela melhorou tudo o que podia e do jeito certo, mas o foco é no Java mesmo, quem mais pra frente eu possa fazer alguma pergunta mais específica sobre a Noda, até com subsídio do que for respondido aqui.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

De modo geral, a decisão de usar ou não uma linguagem/framework/biblioteca/tecnologia depende de vários fatores (desde aspectos técnicos até gosto pessoal). No caso específico do Joda-Time, acho que vale "dar uma geral" na biblioteca, vendo seu histórico e listando algumas semelhanças e diferenças com relação ao `java.time`, e aí cada um tira suas próprias conclusões.

## Breve - mas nem tanto - resumo do Joda-Time

Por muito tempo o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) foi a melhor alternativa para a API nativa de datas do Java, pois na época tudo que tínhamos eram as classes [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (além de seus "amigos": [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), [`java.util.TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) e as classes [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), [`Time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) e [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) do pacote [`java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html)). Todas elas possuem uma [longa lista de problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442) e [falhas de *design*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) (não vou listar tudo, mas alguns serão citados abaixo, quando forem pertinentes à discussão).

Uma das inovações do Joda-Time (que hoje pode parecer "batido" e trivial, mas na época foi motivo de "uau!") foi a API fluida e mais simples de usar. Por exemplo, para criar uma data específica e somar alguns dias e meses à mesma:

```
// antes do Joda-Time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2019, Calendar.JANUARY, 20); // 20 de janeiro de 2019
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5); // somar 5 dias
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3); // somar 3 meses
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // Thu Apr 25 16:15:27 BRT 2019

// depois do Joda-Time
LocalDate data = new LocalDate(2019, 1, 20) // 20 de janeiro de 2019
    .plusDays(5) // somar 5 dias
    .plusMonths(3); // somar 3 meses
System.out.println(data); // 2019-04-25
```

No código acima podemos perceber outros detalhes. A API nativa só possuía duas classes para representar datas e horas:

- `Date`: que apesar do nome, [não representa uma data (um único dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo)](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), e sim um [timestamp](/q/70473/112052) (um instante, um ponto específico na linha do tempo, que pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do fuso horário).
- `Calendar`: que possui um timestamp **e** um timezone (fuso horário), e portanto representa uma data e hora em um fuso horário específico

Já o Joda-Time criou [várias classes diferentes](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html#Date_and_Time) para representar conceitos como "apenas uma data (dia, mês e ano)", "apenas horário", "data e hora com (ou sem) fuso horário", etc. Isso foi outra grande inovação, pois com `Date` e `Calendar`, você sempre está lidando com timestamps direta ou indiretamente. `Calendar` ainda tem um timezone embutido, sempre agindo "por trás dos panos", então ajustes como o horário de verão podem ocorrer sem que você perceba. Já no Joda-Time você pode escolher quais campos vai usar e ter um controle maior sobre as datas e horas.

Repare no exemplo acima. Ao imprimir `cal.getTime()`, o retorno é um `java.util.Date`, que ao ser impresso chama o método [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString()), que por sua vez usa o timezone *default* da JVM para saber qual a data e hora a ser exibida - comportamento que é explicado [aqui](/a/372560/112052) e [aqui](/a/370367/112052) (na seção "Datas e timezones"). E como eu só setei o dia, mês e ano, os campos de horário continuaram setados para a hora atual (no momento em que o `Calendar` foi criado com [`getInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance())). Já se usar um [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html), não ocorrem esses problemas. Como essa classe não tem os campos de horário, eles sequer são mostrados ao imprimir a data. E como essa classe também não tem informações de fuso horário, ela não sofre interferência do timezone *default* da JVM.

Outra *grande* melhoria foi usar os valores corretos para os meses. Na API nativa, os meses eram indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), e até hoje tem vezes em que eu esqueço e acabo usando o valor errado. Por isso eu preferi usar a constante [`Calendar.JANUARY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) ([cujo valor é zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.JANUARY), aliás), que é menos propenso a erros. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas a [API do JavaScript tem esse mesmo problema](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), e [até hoje causa confusão](/q/405994/112052) entre os desenvolvedores.

Outras características são classes imutáveis e *thread safe*, uma [API de formatação e *parsing*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html) muito superior a `SimpleDateFormat` (que corrige [vários problemas bizarros desta](https://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/sdf/), além de ser mais flexível e completa), suporte mais detalhado a timezones, [suporte a outros calendários](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_chronology.html), além de classes para representar durações (quantidades de tempo), algo que não existia na API nativa. E também outras facilidades, como os métodos de comparação `isBefore` e `isAfter` (mais claros e semânticos que `compareTo`), *getters* específicos para obter o dia, o mês, o ano, etc (versus o "*getter* genérico" de `Calendar`, que te obriga a fazer coisas como `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`, [conversões de/para a API nativa](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/userguide.html#JDK_Interoperability) e muitas outras "coisinhas" que somadas, faziam do Joda-Time a API de datas preferida deste que vos escreve (*hoje não é mais*).

---

Nos comentários foi indicada [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375544) sobre as desvantagens do Joda-Time. [A resposta do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/375803) diz que um dos problemas foi quando ele tentou escrever seu próprio timezone. Bom, ainda estou para ver uma API que permita fazer isso de maneira fácil (eu também já tentei com o Joda-Time e outras APIs, e não é algo trivial dependendo do que você quer fazer), mas de qualquer forma é um caso de uso raro (eu só fiz por curiosidade) e eu não consideraria um problema tão grave assim. Até porque não é simples mesmo, e eu entendo que nenhuma API tenha disponibilizado uma forma fácil de fazê-lo. Para a grande maioria dos casos, usar os timezones que já existem é o suficiente.

Outro ponto que você pode considerar uma vantagem ou desvantagem é que as [informações dos timezones](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) ficam no próprio JAR do Joda-Time, separadas da JVM. Por um lado pode ser bom, porque [você pode atualizá-las separadamente](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html), sem precisar mexer na instalação do Java. Por outro lado pode ser ruim, porque é mais um lugar para mudar (já que *geralmente* atualiza-se - ou deveriam atualizar - a JVM também, pois é de lá que a API nativa lê essas informações). Enfim, essa "desvantagem" eu considero discutível: há casos em que a atualização da JVM está a cargo de outra equipe e você não pode esperá-los, então usar o Joda-Time garantiria que pelo menos a sua aplicação estará com as informações atualizadas (mas se ela fizer conversões de/para a API legada, aí não tem jeito, tem que atualizar a JVM também).

Enfim, não vou comentar todas as respostas uma a uma, até porque algumas podem estar desatualizadas (a pergunta é de 2008), mas uma das desvantagens é justamente o fato de ser **um projeto que se declarou como encerrado**. Vendo as [últimas versões](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/changes-report.html), a maioria são atualizações de timezones ou pequenas correções. Além disso, em seu próprio site [há um aviso](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/#Support):

> *Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely "finished" project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310).*

Em tradução livre:

> Joda-Time é considerado um projeto "encerrado". Não há grandes melhorias planejadas. Se estiver usando Java 8, por favor migre para o `java.time` (JSR-310).

Ou seja, o próprio Joda-Time está dizendo "*não me usem, vão para o `java.time`*". Então vamos...

---

## O caminho para a API `java.time`

Quando foi anunciado que [Stephen Colebourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen) (o criador do Joda-Time) seria um dos líderes da [JSR-310](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (que daria origem a uma nova API de datas no Java, o `java.time`), muita gente - inclusive eu - achou que ele iria simplesmente copiar ou adaptar o Joda-Time, fazer alguns ajustes aqui e ali, e pronto. Mas não foi bem isso que aconteceu.

Em [seu blog](https://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html), Stephen explica algumas das coisas que ele considera falhas de *design* no Joda-Time, e que ele decidiu corrigir na nova API. A primeira é a dicotomia entre as formas como humanos e máquinas "enxergam" o conceito de "tempo".

Basicamente, humanos criaram vários conceitos diferentes, como por exemplo os sistemas de calendários (temos o calendário Gregoriano, Budista, Hebraico, Chinês, Japonês, Hindu, etc), que dividem a linha do tempo em pedaços arbitrários: anos, meses, dias, horas, minutos e segundos. Sem contar a grande bagunça que são os fusos horários, com [suas constantes mudanças de regras](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/) (sempre tem alguém querendo mudar o fuso horário do seu país/estado/cidade/província/etc, ou querendo adotar/abolir o horário de verão, para que "o povo tenha mais horas de sol" ou qualquer outro motivo que seja).

Graças a esses conceitos e definições, o mesmo instante pode representar uma data e hora completamente diferentes, dependendo do sistema que você usa (seja um fuso horário ou um calendário diferente). Por exemplo, quando é dia 1 de outubro de 2019, às 18:00 no horário de Brasília, em Tóquio, já é dia 2, às 6 da manhã. Mas se considerarmos o [calendário Copta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coptic_calendar), esta mesma data corresponde ao dia 20 do mês 1 do ano 1736 (para saber disso, usei [esta classe](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/chrono/CopticDate.html), também feita por Stephen Colebourne, então se estiver errada reclamem com ele :P).

Enfim, a visão humana do tempo é um dos lados da moeda. O outro é a "visão das máquinas", que seria o já citado [timestamp](/q/70473/112052): um número que representa a quantidade de segundos (ou milissegundos, ou nanossegundos, varia conforme a implementação) decorrida desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (1970-01-01T00:00Z - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). Esse número é "absoluto", no sentido de ser o mesmo para todos, independente do fuso horário, calendário, etc. Apesar de ser possível converter um timestamp para uma data e hora em determinado calendário e timezone (e vice-versa), são 2 conceitos separados.

No Joda-Time há as classes [`org.joda.time.Instant`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Instant.html) (que representa a "visão da máquina") e [`org.joda.time.DateTime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) (que representa a "visão humana"), mas ambas implementam a interface [`org.joda.time.ReadableInstant`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableInstant.html) (que também representa a "visão da máquina"). Ou seja, temos uma classe que representa um conceito (`DateTime`), mas que implementa uma interface que representa outro completamente diferente. Essa é uma das falhas de *design* que ele quis corrigir na nova API.

---

A outra falha (segundo o autor) é que todas as classes de data e hora do Joda-Time possuem uma cronologia plugável (sendo que "cronologia" é um sinônimo para "sistema de calendário", pois [há uma classe de cronologia para cada calendário](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/chrono/package-summary.html)). Sendo assim, há alguns casos em que isso pode afetar alguns campos, como por exemplo o valor máximo que o mês pode ter (alguns calendários possuem anos com 13 meses). Em várias classes é possível mudar a cronologia, dando margem para códigos confusos e propensos a erros (já que quase ninguém lembra de verificar se a cronologia usada é a correta - a maioria nem concebe a possibilidade de estar usando um calendário diferente).

Como a maioria das aplicações usuais vai acabar usando o [calendário ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (que é o que usamos no dia-a-dia), ele achou melhor deixar este como o *default* da nova API, e datas que usam outros calendários teriam suas próprias classes (como podemos ver no [pacote `java.time.chrono`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/package-summary.html)).

As outras falhas mencionadas são:

- uso de `null` em muitos pontos da API, que dependendo do contexto pode significar o *Unix Epoch*, ou uma duração de valor zero, o que segundo o autor não foi uma boa decisão, por causar muitos *bugs*. Na nova API, muitas classes e métodos verificam se os valores são nulos e lançam uma exceção.
- por causa dos problemas já citados (em especial do primeiro), muitos detalhes internos de implementação acabaram ficando bem complexos. Ele menciona que também aproveitou para consolidar melhor alguns conceitos e comportamentos da API, como o que fazer nas transições de horário de verão (o Joda-Time pode dar erro em alguns casos, enquanto o `java.time` faz alguns ajustes automáticos) e em alguns *corner cases* na aritmética de datas (Ex: quantos anos há entre 29/02/2020 e 28/02/2021? Para o Joda-Time, a resposta é `1`, para o `java.time`, é zero - [veja aqui](https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/JodaTimeDiferencaDatas#Main.java)) - este último não é mencionado no blog, mas não acredito que ele tenha mudado à toa.

Por fim, o próprio autor menciona que a "*JSR-310 começou do zero, mas com uma API **inspirada** pelo Joda-Time*".

---

#### Semelhanças e diferenças entre Joda-Time e `java.time`

[Aqui](https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) e [aqui](/q/177129/112052) tem um ótimo resumo, e pelas tabelas do primeiro link dá para ver que vários conceitos do Joda-Time estão presentes no `java.time`:

- [classes específicas para cada situação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html): uma só para data (dia, mês e ano), outra para o horário, outra para data e hora (sem fuso horário), outra para data e hora em um fuso horário, etc. Interessante notar que algumas classes foram adicionadas, com destaque para os `enum`'s para os [meses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) e os [dias da semana](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html).
- o Joda-Time possui versões mutáveis das classes, que foram removidas no `java.time` (na nova API, todas as classes são imutáveis e *thread safe*)
- no `java.time` os conceitos de timezone e [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) foram separados, o que é algo bem raro de se ver. A grande maioria das API's trata-os como se fossem a mesma coisa, mas há uma diferença sutil: o *offset* é simplesmente a diferença com relação a UTC (como `-03:00` para indicar 3 horas atrás do UTC), já um timezone contém o histórico de alterações do *offset* de uma determinada região do planeta (como `America/Sao_Paulo`, que contém todas as mudanças do Horário Oficial de Brasília, no qual usa-se `-03:00` durante parte do ano, e muda para `-02:00` durante o horário de verão). Para mais detalhes, veja a [wiki da tag timezone](/tags/timezone/info) (na seção "Diferenças entre timezone e *offset*").
- uma coisa que não entendi foi a remoção da formatação de durações (embora menos comum que a formatação de datas, não deixa de ser um caso de uso relativamente comum)

Embora muitas classes (principalmente o *core* das API's) tenham os mesmos nomes e métodos, alguns detalhes em seu funcionamento são diferentes. Um que se nota de cara é o uso de [*factory methods*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method) em vez de construtores:

```java
// Java 8, uso dos factory methods "of()" e "now()"
java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 2, 1);
java.time.LocalDate.now(); // data atual

// Joda-Time, uso de construtor
new org.joda.time.LocalDate(2018, 2, 1);
new org.joda.time.LocalDate(); // data atual
```

<sup>*Note que usei o nome completo das classes para não ficar confuso*.</sup>

Outra diferença são os já citados `enum`'s para o mês e o dia da semana. No Joda-Time, o método `getDayOfWeek()`, por exemplo, retorna um `int` cujos valores são definidos na classe [`org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html). Esta classe enumera os dias da semana segundo a definição da ISO 8601, que considera a Segunda-feira como o primeiro dia da semana. Assim, Segunda-feira (`DateTimeConstants.MONDAY`) tem o valor 1, Terça-feira é 2, e assim por diante, até Domingo, cujo valor é 7.

O fato de existir um tipo `java.time.DayOfWeek` no Java 8 torna o código mais claro e menos propenso a erros, já que não corremos o risco de passar um valor inválido caso um método esteja esperando um dia da semana, pois serão aceitos somente aqueles definidos no `enum`. O mesmo vale para `java.time.Month`, que é o `enum` para os meses (e janeiro tem o valor 1 \o/).

---

Uma das principais diferenças entre as API's está na forma como são tratados os *DST gaps* (quando começa o horário de verão e relógio é adiantado em uma hora). Vamos usar o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` como exemplo. Neste timezone, em 15 de outubro de 2017, à meia-noite, os relógios foram adiantados em uma hora. Isso quer dizer que esta hora foi "pulada", ou seja, todos os minutos entre 00:00 e 00:59 não existem neste dia, para o timezone em questão.

No `java.time` isto é resolvido ajustando o horário para a próxima hora válida. Por exemplo, ao criar um `ZonedDateTime` para "15 de outubro de 2017 à meia-noite e meia em São Paulo", o horário é ajustado automaticamente para 01:30 (a próxima hora válida):

```java
// 15 de outubro de 2017, meia-noite e meia, timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 10, 15, 0, 30, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
// Devido ao horário de verão, 00:30 é ajustado para 01:30
System.out.println(z); // 2017-10-15T01:30-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

Esta é uma abordagem interessante da API, pois simula uma pessoa adiantando manualmente o relógio ao reparar que o horário estava incorreto. Já no Joda-Time, este ajuste não é feito e a tentativa de criar esta data lança uma exceção:

```java
// 15 de outubro de 2017, meia-noite e meia, timezone America/Sao_Paulo
DateTime d = new DateTime(2017, 10, 15, 0, 30, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

Este código lança a seguinte exceção:

> org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 2017-10-15T00:30:00.000 (America/Sao_Paulo)

Repare que a descrição da exceção informa que houve um *DST gap* e por isso o horário informado não existe naquele dia, para o timezone em questão. Para criar um `DateTime` válido, você deve primeiro verificar se a data e hora estão em um *DST gap*, e caso esteja, ajustar o horário para a próxima hora. Para isso, vamos criar um `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone` para o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` e um `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` para verificar se a data e hora estão em um *DST gap*:

```java
// timezone America/Sao_Paulo
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo");
// 15 de outubro de 2017, meia-noite e meia (sem timezone)
LocalDateTime localDt = new LocalDateTime(2017, 10, 15, 0, 30, 0, 0);
// se o localDt está em um DST gap, ajustar para a hora seguinte
if (zone.isLocalDateTimeGap(localDt)) {
    localDt = localDt.plusHours(1);
}
// criar o DateTime: 15 de outubro de 2017, à 01:30, timezone America/Sao_Paulo
DateTime dt = localDt.toDateTime(zone);
```

O método `isLocalDateTimeGap()` verifica se o `LocalDateTime` está em um *DST gap*, e se for o caso, ajustamos para a próxima hora válida. Na prática, estamos fazendo manualmente o ajuste que `ZonedDateTime` faz automaticamente. **Só há um porém**.

O código acima pode funcionar para grande parte dos casos, mas nem todos os *DST gaps* são de 1 hora. Há timezones, como por exemplo `Australia/Lord_Howe`, que [adiantam o relógio em 30 minutos durante o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/australia/lord-howe-island?year=1980). Ou ainda `Asia/Kuching`, que [nos anos 30 adiantava o relógio em apenas 20 minutos](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/malaysia/kuching?year=1925).

Além disso, nem todos os *gaps* são por causa do horário de verão. Há casos em que determinada região simplesmente muda seu fuso horário de forma "definitiva" (entre aspas porque nada garante que não mudará novamente). Um exemplo é a Coreia do Norte, que no dia 5 de maio de 2018 à meia-noite adiantou o relógio em 30 minutos, para alinhar seu horário com a Coreia do Sul. É um *gap* de 30 minutos, porém não relacionado ao horário de verão. Mas por ser um *gap*, também pode causar um `IllegalInstantException`.

Outro exemplo notável é o caso de Samoa: em 30 de dezembro de 2011 à meia-noite eles mudaram seu offset de `-10:00` para `+14:00`. Com isso, [todo o dia 30 foi pulado](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-dateline.html), ou seja, um *gap* de 24 horas! Todos os horários do dia 30 de dezembro de 2011 não existem neste timezone. Isso só foi possível porque o país está localizado próximo à [Linha Internacional de Data](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dateline.html).

Por isso, a solução anterior (somar 1 hora ao `LocalDateTime`) não funciona bem para estes casos. No caso de Samoa, por exemplo, teríamos que somar pelo menos 24 horas para ter certeza que não estamos mais dentro do *gap*. Mas ao somar 24 horas, corremos o risco de obter uma data "adiantada" demais. Um jeito de contornar isso seria ir somando 1 minuto, até encontrar um horário válido:

```java
// ajustar para o minuto seguinte, até encontrar uma hora que não está em um gap
while (zone.isLocalDateTimeGap(localDt)) {
    localDt = localDt.plusMinutes(1);
}
```

Com isso, o `LocalDateTime` vai sendo incrementado até encontrarmos um horário válido que não esteja em um *gap*, não importando se é relacionado a horário de verão ou não, nem se é de 1 hora, 20 minutos ou um dia inteiro. Já o `java.time` faz estes ajustes automaticamente, sempre avançando para uma data e hora válidas.

---

O `java.time` também mudou algumas coisas para formatação e *parsing* de datas. Alguns *patterns* não funcionam da mesma maneira: no Joda-Time, a letra `e` representa o dia da semana conforme os valores das respectivas constantes na classe `DateTimeConstants`, que já vimos anteriormente: Segunda-feira tem valor 1, Terça-feira é 2 etc. Porém, no `java.time`, a letra `e` representa o dia da semana conforme o `Locale` utilizado (e se nenhum `Locale` for informado, é usado o locale padrão da JVM). De acordo com o `Locale`, a semana pode começar no Sábado, Domingo ou Segunda-feira, então um `DateTimeFormatter` com a letra `e` pode retornar um valor diferente para a mesma data, dependendo do `Locale` utilizado (algo que não ocorre no Joda-Time, que usa uma definição de semana que não depende do `Locale`). [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46343732) tem uma explicação bem detalhada sobre isso.

Outra coisa que foi - na minha opinião - melhorada são `TemporalField` e `TemporalUnit`, que correspondem respectivamente a campos de uma data (como o dia, o mês, o ano, etc) e unidades de uma duração (dias, meses, horas, minutos, etc). Esses conceitos também existem no Joda-Time mas eu sempre achei meio confuso de usá-los, e no `java.time` me parece que ficou mais fácil de entender e usar (mas aí já é minha opinião).

Existem ainda algumas novidades que o Joda-Time não tem:

- a interface [`TemporalQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/adjusters.html), que permite obter informações de uma data de maneira mais customizada. Ex:

  ```
  TemporalQuery<MeuResponseCustomizado> info = (t) -> {
      DayOfWeek dow = DayOfWeek.from(t); // obtém o dia da semana
      MeuResponseCustomizado resp;
      if (condicaoComplexa(dow)) {
          resp = fazAlgoBemComplicado(t);
      } else {
          resp = respostaDefault(t);
      }
      return resp;
  };
  MeuResponseCustomizado resposta = LocalDate.now().query(info);
  ```

  O detalhe é que um `TemporalQuery` recebe como parâmetro um `TemporalAccessor` (uma interface que todas as classes de data da API implementam), tornando-a bem flexível (é possível usar a mesma `TemporalQuery` com várias classes diferentes). Claro que no Joda-Time bastaria criar um método estático em uma classe utilitária, mas o `TemporalQuery` facilita algumas coisas (como a utilização do padrão *Strategy*, poder passar a query como parâmetro, trocá-la por *mocks* nos testes, etc)
- a interface [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/adjusters.html), para ajustes úteis, como obter o último dia do mês, a terceira quinta-feira do mês, entre outros. Estes que citei, inclusive, [já estão prontos na própria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html).
- [`java.time.Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/clock.html), com o qual é possível mudar a data/hora atual ([muito útil em testes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27067049), por exemplo). No Joda-Time isso era feito com um [método estático](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeUtils.html#setCurrentMillisFixed-long-), que mudava a data/hora atual para toda a aplicação, já no `java.time` você pode ter vários `Clock`'s diferentes ao mesmo tempo, eles podem ser configurados pelo *container* de injeção de dependência, etc.

Outra diferença é que o `java.time` possui precisão de nanossegundos (9 casas decimais na fração de segundos), enquanto a precisão do Joda-Time é de milissegundos (3 casas decimais). Dependendo do que você precisa, isso pode ou não ser uma grande vantagem.

Enfim, há vários outros detalhes que são diferentes ([tenho uma classe no GitHub que detalha melhor esses e outros pontos](https://github.com/hkotsubo/java-datetime-book/blob/master/src/main/java/outros/JodaTimeExemplos.java)), mas resumindo:

- alguns conceitos e ideias do Joda-Time foram aproveitados no `java.time`
- algumas coisas foram melhoradas e não funcionam exatamente da mesma maneira
- outras foram completamente modificadas, e alguns conceitos novos adicionados
- a nova API é inspirada na antiga, mas não é uma mera cópia

## Mas devo usar ou não?

Na minha opinião: em projetos novos usando JDK >= 8, use o `java.time`. A API supre a maioria das necessidades que o Joda-Time proporcionava, e o suporte das API's "famosas" só aumenta: o Jackson já possui um módulo próprio, o JDBC 4.2 já suporta estas classes (verifique se o seu banco de dados já tem um *driver* compatível) e por aí vai.

Se estiver usando JDK 6 ou 7, use o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* que possui a maioria das funcionalidades do `java.time`. A API é praticamente a mesma (salvo alguns detalhes, como a conversão de/para `Date` e `Calendar`, que no Java 8 é feito [através de novos métodos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/legacy.html), e no *backport* é feito por uma [classe utilitária](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html)). Além de ter as mesmas funcionalidades, isso facilita uma futura migração para o JDK 8, pois para a maioria dos casos bastaria mudar o `import` de `org.threeten.bp` para `java.time`.

Para Android, o `java.time` também está disponível ([aqui](/a/190262/112052) tem instruções para usá-la), mas também é possível usar o *backport* ([aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754) tem instruções para usá-lo em Android).

Mas caso você ainda esteja preso ao JDK 5 (não duvido que ainda exista), não há perspectiva de mudar a versão, e quer usar algo melhor que `Date` e `Calendar`, nesse caso eu recomendo o Joda-Time. Outro caso é quando há muito código legado usando Joda-Time e é inviável migrá-lo (sendo que "muito" e "inviável" podem ser subjetivos, mas se está considerando continuar ou não usando, é uma análise que tem que ser feita).

---

<sup>*[Esta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24631909) também compara as 2 API's. Quanto ao NodaTime, não conheço o suficiente para dizer algo significativo.*</sup>

Comment: Já vai o +1 só pelo esforço (e sei que é ótimo), assim não corro o risco de ficar sem votos hoje (já tá quase :D)

Comment: @Maniero Obrigado pela confiança. Bem que estranhei um voto tão rápido :-)

Comment: Que resposta, muito obrigado @hkotsubo, bem detalhada.

Comment: Eu estou pensando em portar a Joda Money pra .NET. Já fizeram mas pioraram muito. E mesmo a Joda acho bem ruim. Tem motivos mais importantes, mas uma das coisas que eu acho que precisa é poder criar sua própria moeda, coisa corriqueira no Brasil :D Por isso guarda alguma semelhança, e por isso que estou tendo colher mais informações sobre o port do Jon Skeet, que até onde eu sei é melhor que a Joda TIme. Não sei se sabe algo da Money. Só preciso consolidar ideias e arrumar tempo para começar fazer o port dela, embora nem sei se dá pra falar em port de tão diferente que será.

Comment: A resposta me ajudou pensar em algumas coisas sobre o Money. Tem algum lugar fácil pra ver a implementação disto? Em específico qual o tamanho do objeto que guarda tempo? Algo me diz que ele é grande demais pra algo desnecessário. Se me lembro bem você não consegue armazenar todos os nanossegundos (consegue preciso de 100 deles) em até de 64bits, o que é uma pena, mas eu já esperaria isso de Java e considerando que é uma classe nem faz tanta diferença assim.

Comment: @Maniero Nunca usei o Joda-Money. Sobre o NodaTime, [aqui](https://nodatime.org/2.0.x/userguide/rationale) diz que várias coisas do Joda-Time foram mudadas por serem consideradas erros (mas não diz quais). Talvez na [lista de discussão](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/noda-time) vc consiga mais detalhes. Como eu já disse, não conheço a fundo esta lib, então não sei quais os pontos que foram alterados/melhorados.

Comment: @Maniero Sobre a implementação do Java, eu sugiro o [repositório do OpenJDK](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/time). Sei que os nanossegundos ficam em um campo `int` separado. Um `Instant`, por exemplo, tem 2 campos para o timestamp: um `long` com a quantidade de segundos e um `int` com os nanossegundos (e métodos como `toEpochMilli` e `ofEpochMilli`, que trabalham com o valor em milissegundos, fazem as devidas contas necessárias).

Comment: Já li bastante sobre a Noda. O lugar mais fácil que pode ajudar https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188110/noda-time-vs-joda-time. Muitas das mudanças é o fato de C# ser uma linguagem bem melhor :P