# Formatação de string com durações

Tags: java

Tenho uma string de tempo com minutos, segundos e milissegundos.
Exemplo: `1:25.684`

Como posso formatar essa String para um formato completo de hora, preenchendo com 0, para ficar assim:

> ```
> 00:01:25.684
> ```

```
String tempo = "1:25.684";
MaskFormatter f = new MaskFormatter("##:##:##.###");
String s = f.valueToString(tempo);
```

Mas ocorre o seguinte erro:

> java.text.ParseException: Invalid character

Answer (score 1):

Receio que você tenha que fazer o *parsing* e a formatação manualmente. Como não ficou claro quais os formatos possíveis, tentei fazer de uma maneira meio "genérica":

```
// método para separar segundos das frações de segundo
public int[] separarSegundosMs(String s) {
    String[] partes = s.split("\\.");
    if (partes.length == 1) { // não tem milissegundos
        return new int[] { Integer.parseInt(partes[0]), 0 };
    }
    return new int[] { Integer.parseInt(partes[0]), Integer.parseInt(partes[1]) };
}

...
String tempo = "1:25.684";
int horas = 0, minutos = 0, segundos = 0, fracoesSegundo = 0;
String[] partes = tempo.split(":");
int[] secs = null;
switch (partes.length) {
    case 1:// só segundos
        secs = separarSegundosMs(partes[0]);
        break;
    case 2:// só tem minutos e segundos
        minutos = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
        secs = separarSegundosMs(partes[1]);
        break;
    case 3:// tem horas, minutos e segundos
        horas = Integer.parseInt(partes[0]);
        minutos = Integer.parseInt(partes[1]);
        secs = separarSegundosMs(partes[2]);
        break;
}
if (secs != null) {
    segundos = secs[0];
    fracoesSegundo = secs[1];
}

String formatado = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d.%d", horas, minutos, segundos, fracoesSegundo);
System.out.println(formatado); // 00:01:25.684
```

Primeiro eu faço um [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) separando as partes por `:`. Aí eu vejo quantas partes tem, para saber se a `String` contém ou não as horas, minutos, segundos, etc. Para os segundos e milissegundos, usei outro `split`, separando por `.` (como `split` recebe uma regex e [o ponto possui significado especial em regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), precisei fazer o escape com `\`).

Ao formatar, usei o formato `%02d` (usa dois dígitos, preenchendo com zero à esquerda se necessário). Para as frações de segundo só usei `%d`, pois se a entrada for `03:02.5`, a fração de segundo é `5`, então não deve ter zeros à esquerda (do contrário a saída seria `03:02.05`, que seria um valor diferente do original).

---

### Joda-Time

Outra opção, se quiser usar uma biblioteca externa, é usar o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Você pode criar um [`PeriodFormatter`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatter.html) para os casos que tem horas e outro para os casos em que não tem (e aí você tenta fazer o *parsing* com um, e se não der, tenta com outro):

```
PeriodFormatter comHoras = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().minimumPrintedDigits(2)
    // horas
    .printZeroAlways().appendHours().appendSeparator(":")
    // minutos
    .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
    // segundos
    .appendSeconds().appendSeparator(".")
    // frações de segundos
    .minimumPrintedDigits(0).appendMillis()
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
PeriodFormatter semmHoras = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    // minutos
    .appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":")
    // segundos
    .appendSeconds().appendSeparator(".")
    // frações de segundos
    .appendMillis()
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
Period period = null;
try {
    period = comHoras.parsePeriod(tempo);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    period = semmHoras.parsePeriod(tempo);
}
if (period != null) {
    System.out.println(comHoras.print(period)); // 00:01:25.684
}
```

Para imprimir, usei o *formatter* com as horas, assim todos os campos são impressos, mesmo que sejam zero. Também usei `minimumPrintedDigits(2)` para que os valores tenham o zero à esquerda quando necessário.

Vale lembrar que o Joda-Time é uma API descontinuada ([veja mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413649/112052)) e eu só sugeri porque a API padrão do Java não tem suporte a *parsing* e formatação customizada de durações. Aliás, esse é o problema da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450367/112052), que está tratando a duração como se fosse uma data.

---

Existe uma diferença entre esses dois conceitos. Considere as frases abaixo:

- o filme começa às duas horas
- o filme tem duração de duas horas

No primeiro caso, estou falando de um horário (um momento específico do dia). No segundo caso, estou falando de uma duração (uma quantidade de tempo), mas não necessariamente estou dizendo quando o filme começa (na verdade não diz nem se ele vai passar, só diz quanto tempo ele dura).

O problema é que usamos as mesmas palavras para ambos ("horas", "minutos", etc). Mas no seu caso, a string representa uma duração, e não uma data ou horário.

A outra resposta sugere usar [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) e [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), que são classes que servem para trabalhar com datas e horas, **mas não com durações**. Apesar de às vezes "funcionar", é um uso torto dessas classes e bem propenso a erros (e nem entrei no mérito de que o código lá retornava - [antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/b38c2930-5353-4852-8a11-6f0a60332c40/view-source) - `12:01:25.684`, ou de que ele falhará para durações maiores que 24 horas).

A API nativa possui suporte à durações a partir do Java 8, nas classes [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) e [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html), mas infelizmente elas não possuem métodos prontos para fazer *parsing* e formatação customizadas, por isso as melhores opções continuam sendo fazer manualmente ou usar uma biblioteca externa.

---

Antes que alguém sugira essa gambiarra, já vou colocar aqui e alertar para os problemas:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("00:0" + tempo);
System.out.println(time);
```

A classe [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) (disponível a partir do Java 8) representa um horário, não uma duração. Apesar de "funcionar" para esse caso específico, é um uso torto da mesma, pelos motivos já comentados acima. Além disso, ela só suporta valores para o horário entre 0 e 23, então se você tiver uma duração de 24 horas ou mais, ela já não funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar assim.

Na formatação de saída ficou o valor da hora fixo já que você só está tratando minutos e segundos então a hora sempre vai ser 00.

```
    String input = "1:25.684";

    DateFormat formatacaoEntrada = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss.SSS");

    DateFormat formatacaoSaida = new SimpleDateFormat("00:mm:ss.SSS");

    String horaConvertida = null;

    try {

        Date entradaFormatadaComoData = formatacaoEntrada.parse(input);

        horaConvertida = formatacaoSaida.format(entradaFormatadaComoData);

        System.out.println(horaConvertida);

    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        pe.printStackTrace();
    }
```