# Verificar se uma data está antes ou depois de outras datas

Tags: java, data

Estou usando Java 7 e preciso verificar se uma data de nascimento está antes ou depois de determinadas datas.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
String  str1 ="31/12/1960";  
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(str1);  

String  str2 ="31/12/2003";  
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(str2); 

if (individuo.getDataNascimento() < date1 && nascimento > date2); {
addmsg ("motivo de isenção nao condiz com a idade");

}
else {
prontuario.setDataNascimento(individuo.getDataNascimento());
            log.info("Data Nascimento Indivíduo: " + prontuario.getDataNascimentoFormatado());

}
```

O problema é que os símbolos de `<` e `>` não são reconhecidos e ele não compila.

Answer (score 2):

Para comparar se uma data vem antes ou depois de outra, use os métodos [`before`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before-java.util.Date-) e [`after`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-):

```
if (individuo.getDataNascimento().before(date1) || individuo.getDataNascimento().after(date2)) {
   etc...
}
```

Um detalhe é que na verdade acho que você deveria usar o operador `||` ("or") em vez de `&&` ("and"). Pois o `&&` verifica se ambas as condições são verdadeiras, e não tem como uma data ser ao mesmo tempo antes de 1960 e depois de 2003 (ou é um, ou outro, ambos ao mesmo tempo não dá, então se usar `&&` nunca entrará neste `if`).

---

Outro detalhe é que você não precisa criar um novo `SimpleDateFormat` toda hora. Se o formato das strings não muda, basta reaproveitar o mesmo:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String str1 ="31/12/1960";
Date date1 = sdf.parse(str1);

String str2 ="31/12/2003";
Date date2 = sdf.parse(str2);
```

---

Uma alternativa para Java 7 - caso queira usar uma biblioteca externa - é o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* do [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) (a nova API de datas do Java 8).

Com isso, você pode usar um tipo mais adequado para cada situação. Por exemplo, como a data de nascimento só tem dia, mês e ano, em vez de `Date` você pode usar um [`org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html):

```
public class SuaClasse {
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;

    public LocalDate getDataNascimento() {
        return dataNascimento;
    }

    // etc...
}


DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu");
String str1 = "31/12/1960";
LocalDate inicio = LocalDate.parse(str1, parser);

String str2 = "31/12/2003";
LocalDate fim = LocalDate.parse(str2, parser);

if (individuo.getDataNascimento().isBefore(inicio) || individuo.getDataNascimento().isAfter(fim)) {
    // data está antes de "inicio" ou depois de "fim"
}
```

Pode parecer que "só mudou a classe de data", mas a nova API tem muitas vantagens e melhorias com relação a `Date`, e o seu uso desde já facilitaria uma futura migração para o Java 8, pois bastaria mudar o nome do pacote de `org.threeten.bp` para `java.time` (salvo um ou outro detalhe específico, veja mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413649/112052) - em especial, no final [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052) tem algumas informações sobre o uso do *backport*).