# Formatar datas incluindo o offset

Tags: java, data, simpledateformat

Não estou conseguindo formatar nesse padrão: `2020-10-01T11:34:00.270-03:00`.

```java
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse valor `-03:00` é o [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a diferença com relação a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) - então neste caso seriam "3 horas a menos que UTC"), e segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), basta usar o *pattern* `X` para exibi-lo. No caso, para ter horas e minutos separados por dois-pontos, basta usar 3 letras `X`:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date())); // 2020-10-06T17:02:42.755-03:00
```

Lembrando que o valor do *offset* depende do timezone *default* que está configurado na JVM. No meu caso, o *default* (que pode ser consultado com [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--)) é `America/Sao_Paulo`, [que corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/259120/112052).

Mas se o timezone *default* for outro, será usado o *offset* correspondente. Ex:

```
// setando o timezone default para usar o fuso horário da Alemanha
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date())); // 2020-10-06T22:04:44.057+02:00
```

Mudando o timezone *default* para o fuso da Alemanha, `SimpleDateFormat` usa o *offset* deste fuso. No caso, é `+02:00` (pois [atualmente a Europa está em horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/berlin?year=2020), geralmente a Alemanha usa `+01:00`).

Se quiser que o `SimpleDateFormat` sempre use um timezone específico, independente do que estiver configurado na JVM, basta setar nele:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
// usar o Horário de Brasília, independente do timezone default da JVM
inputFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(inputFormat.format(new Date())); // 2020-10-06T17:07:06.891-03:00
```

Pode não parecer, mas isso é um detalhe importante, pois o timezone *default* é algo que pode não estar no seu controle (por exemplo, os responsáveis pelo servidor podem mudar esta configuração - sem querer ou de propósito - sem te avisar, ou outra aplicação na mesma JVM pode chamar `TimeZone.setDefault()`, etc). Se você depender do *default*, de repente o sistema pode começar a mostrar datas erradas "do nada", mas se você setar o timezone no `SimpleDateFormat`, essas mudanças de configuração não afetarão o seu código.

Esses nomes de timezones no formato `Continente/Regiao` (como `America/Sao_Paulo` e `Europe/Berlin`) são definidos pela [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), e é possível consultar todos os disponíveis usando `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()`.

---

## API `java.time`

Se estiver usando Java >= 8, outra opção é usar a [API `java.time`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) (mais moderna e que resolve [vários problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442) e [falhas de *design*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1571265) de `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`).

No caso, uma opção é usar [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), que é uma classe que possui a data, hora e *offset* (ou seja, todos os campos que você precisa):

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now();
System.out.println(now.toString());
```

Por padrão, o método `toString()` já retorna a data no formato que você precisa (este formato é conhecido como [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).

Vale lembrar que o método [`now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#now--) usa o *offset* baseado no timezone *default* da JVM (ou seja, se o timezone *default* for o da Alemanha, ele usaria `+02:00`, como no exemplo anterior). Se quiser que ele use um timezone específico, independente do que está configurado na JVM, basta passar um [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html):

```
// usa o offset do Horário de Brasília, independente do timezone default configurado na JVM
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(now.toString());
```

Para consultar todos os timezones disponíveis, use `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

Um detalhe é que `toString` pode omitir alguns campos, caso eles sejam zero:

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 10, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-3));
System.out.println(now.toString()); // 2020-10-01T09:00-03:00
```

Repare que os segundos e frações de segundo não aparecem, pois `toString` omite esses campos quando o valor destes é zero. Se quiser **sempre** mostrar esses campos, o jeito é usar um [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```
OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.of(2020, 10, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, ZoneOffset.ofHours(-3));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(now.format(formatter)); // 2020-10-01T09:00:00.000-03:00
```

---

#### Java < 8

Se estiver usando o JDK 6 ou 7 e quiser uma alternativa melhor que `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat`, pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`. O código fica idêntico ao exemplo acima (as mesmas classes e métodos), a única diferença é que as classes ficam no pacote `org.threeten.bp` em vez de `java.time` (isso inclusive facilita uma futura migração para o Java 8, pois bastaria trocar os `import`'s - além de alguns outros detalhes, explicados no final [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052)).

---

E para JDK 5, uma alternativa é o [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). No caso do formato ISO 8601, já existe inclusive um método pronto:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

// data/hora atual em um timezone específico (para não depender do timezone default da JVM)
DateTime now = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
System.out.println(formatter.print(now)); // 2020-10-07T09:31:52.822-03:00
```

Vale lembrar que o Joda-Time é um projeto antigo e encerrado, então sugiro que leia as considerações [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/413649/112052) antes de decidir usá-lo.